# Flutter: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I recently updated the Dart SDK from 2.10.0 to 2.12.0, and now I am constantly getting this error even after trying several things:

```
h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

- running `flutter clean`
- removing Flutter.framework and running pod install
- switching flutter channels to beta and master
- updating pod
- recreating the entire project

After removing the `Flutter.framework` folder and running pod install, the folder doesn't regenerate and also I am not able to see `App.framework` so I copied these 2 folders from a new project and tried to see if that makes it work, but that too fails.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: you can try to regenerate the project, just flutter create <name>, and then copy ios folder to current project

Comment: The content of the folders will be different right? Should I change anything in this folder?